# Refresh Magento cache via SOAP API

Tags: magento, caching, soap

I am coding a sync tool for Magento that utilizes the SOAP-API. So far I can insert, delete and update products and product images, but the changes don't show up until I flush the block HTML output cache. Is there a way to do that via the SOAP-API or do I have to do that manually every time I synchronize with the shop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time I change something in the SOAP API I have the following routine on linux:

1. `rm -rf var/cache/*` - this command is deleting all the magento cache
2. `rm -rf /tmp/wsdl-*` this command is finding the cached version of the soap api and is deleting it no worries after first check of the web service the files will be regenerated.

Comment: So in order to use this solution from a java app, I could create a PHP file on the server that runs the first command on the server. Is the second one really necessary? The only cache my SOAP client affects is the HTML Blocks thingy.

Comment: Usually second one is needed when you do some modifications in wsdl.xml in theory but one time I got null value from my ws, till I did not drop the /tmp/wsdl-*. Keep in mind that first request to ws after deleting those files will be very slow. You should set up the timout_limit higher!